# NodeJS Socket Laggs when much users online and running emits

Tags: node.js

i have a Question.
I have a Site, running with NodeJS and Socket for communicate with the clientside.

When there are only few users, all is fine. If there are much users running things and emits much with the Sockets/NodeJS, than it gets a little bit laggy and all questions need more time for everything.

The Server has much power with 8 cores. More than enaugh and is not busy. Most time 10-20% CPU used...

But why is there so much laggs in so much times? Any ideas? :(

Its normal NodeJS with Socket calling to user and back.
And when user run actions most time MySQL Calls. Sure they need some seconds but so much? I think more its the socket and not mysql

Comment: We don't have any of your code to look at to let us try and find out what's causing your issues, so we can only ask general questions. How often are you emitting from the server? How large are the payloads in these emitted events? How often are you making MySQL queries? And how large is your database?